# how to let spark 2.0 reading mutli folders parquet like csv

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have some daily data to save to multi folders(mostly based on time).  now I have two format to store the files one is parquet and the other is csv , I would like to save to parquet format to save some space.
the folder structure is like following :

```
[root@hdp raw]# tree
.
├── entityid=10001
│   └── year=2017
│       └── quarter=1
│           └── month=1
│               ├── day=6
│               │   └── part-r-00000-84f964ec-f3ea-46fd-9fe6-8b36c2433e8e.snappy.parquet
│               └── day=7
│                   └── part-r-00000-84f964ec-f3ea-46fd-9fe6-8b36c2433e8e.snappy.parquet
├── entityid=100055
│   └── year=2017
│       └── quarter=1
│           └── month=1
│               ├── day=6
│               │   └── part-r-00000-84f964ec-f3ea-46fd-9fe6-8b36c2433e8e.snappy.parquet
│               └── day=7
│                   └── part-r-00000-84f964ec-f3ea-46fd-9fe6-8b36c2433e8e.snappy.parquet
├── entityid=100082
│   └── year=2017
│       └── quarter=1
│           └── month=1
│               ├── day=6
│               │   └── part-r-00000-84f964ec-f3ea-46fd-9fe6-8b36c2433e8e.snappy.parquet
│               └── day=7
│                   └── part-r-00000-84f964ec-f3ea-46fd-9fe6-8b36c2433e8e.snappy.parquet
└── entityid=10012
    └── year=2017
        └── quarter=1
            └── month=1
                ├── day=6
                │   └── part-r-00000-84f964ec-f3ea-46fd-9fe6-8b36c2433e8e.snappy.parquet
                └── day=7
                    └── part-r-00000-84f964ec-f3ea-46fd-9fe6-8b36c2433e8e.snappy.parquet
```

now I have a python list stores all the folders need to be read,suppose each time run it need to read only some of the folders base on filter conditions.

```
folderList=df_inc.collect()
folderString=[]

for x in folderList:
    folderString.append(x.folders)
In [44]: folderString
Out[44]:
[u'/data/raw/entityid=100055/year=2017/quarter=1/month=1/day=7',
 u'/data/raw/entityid=10012/year=2017/quarter=1/month=1/day=6',
 u'/data/raw/entityid=100082/year=2017/quarter=1/month=1/day=7',
 u'/data/raw/entityid=100055/year=2017/quarter=1/month=1/day=6',
 u'/data/raw/entityid=100082/year=2017/quarter=1/month=1/day=6',
 u'/data/raw/entityid=10012/year=2017/quarter=1/month=1/day=7']
```

the files were writen by :

```
df_join_with_time.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("entityid","year","quarter","month","day").mode("append").parquet(rawFolderPrefix)
```

when I try to read the folders stored in folderString by `df_batch=spark.read.parquet(folderString)` error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String encounters.

if I save the files in csv format and read it through below code it just works fine as following: please if anyway to read the filelist for parquet folder ,much appreciate!

```
In [46]: folderList=df_inc.collect()
    ...: folderString=[]
    ...:
    ...: for x in folderList:
    ...:     folderString.append(x.folders)
    ...: df_batch=spark.read.csv(folderString)
    ...:

In [47]: df_batch.show()
+------------+---+-------------------+----------+----------+
|         _c0|_c1|                _c2|       _c3|       _c4|
+------------+---+-------------------+----------+----------+
|6C25B9C3DD54|  1|2017-01-07 00:00:01|1483718401|1483718400|
|38BC1ADB0164|  3|2017-01-06 00:00:01|1483632001|1483632000|
|38BC1ADB0164|  3|2017-01-07 00:00:01|1483718401|1483718400|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved by :

```
df=spark.read.parquet(folderString[0])
y=0
for x in folderString:
    if y>0:
        df=df.union(spark.read.parquet(x))
    y=y+1
```

it's a very ugly solution ,if you have good idea ,please let me know. many thanks.

few days later,found the perfect way to solve the problem by:

```
df=spark.read.parquet(*folderString)
```

Comment: But if you point to the raw folder. Like `spark.read.parquet('/data/raw')` it will work properly.

Comment: thank you for the comment , I don't want to read all the folders under /data/raw, only some of them which stores in the list variable folderString

Answer (score 2):

You are facing a miss understanding of partition in Hadoop and Parquet.

See, I have a simple file structure partitioned by year-month. It is like this:

```
my_folder
.
├── year-month=2016-12
|   └── my_files.parquet
├── year-month=2016-11
|   └── my_files.parquet
```

If I make a read from `my_folder` without any filter in my dataframe reader like this:

```
df = saprk.read.parquet("path/to/my_folder")
df.show()
```

If you check the Spark DAG visualization you can see that in this case it will read all my partitions as you said:

[image]

In the case above, each point in the first square is one partition of my data.

But if I change my code to this:

```
df = saprk.read.parquet("path/to/my_folder")\
          .filter((col('year-month') >= lit(my_date.strftime('%Y-%m'))) &
                  (col('year-month') <= lit(my_date.strftime('%Y-%m'))))
```

The DAG visualization will show how many partitions I'm using:

[image]

So, if you filter by the column that is the partition you will not read all the files. Just that you need, you don't need to use that solution of reading one folder by folder.

Comment: Hi Thiago, thank you for the response, my problem is that the folders I need to read is random. it's totally based on today's incremental file and the file might contain any day's data , I could figure out them by today's file by grouping by day. that's df_inc is for. once I know that which day(surely include today) need to be recaculated ,I will read both the history file and today's incremental change . so I wish I could read all the files contains the df_inc and couldn't provide an exact filter . the very same method is just working perfectly if I read by csv method .